# excel - timesheet if day before and day after holiday worked

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]
I currently have if the holiday add 8 hours with the following formula.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT(B5,"mmm"),3)=LEFT(Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,3))*(DAY(B5)=--RIGHT(Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,2))),8,0)
```

I think what I'm asking for would go where the 8 currently is.

So what I am attempting to do is only add those 8 hours if the scheduled working day before the holiday, and the scheduled working day after the holiday is worked.  Now I know this wont put the +8 hours in until the information for the following day is entered but that is fine as long as the week end totals include the holiday.

Is there any way I can go about achieving this?

Comment: What if holiday is at the beginning/end of the week/month? How can you check previous/next day in that case?

Comment: touche... hmm, maybe I should just leave it a manually entered field...

Comment: then again looking at our work holidays they all fall within the frame it would take to do the check so this could work. (atleast for the rest of this year)

Comment: So what does happen if the holiday is on a Monday or on a Friday?

Answer (score 0):

So, as a temporary solution you can use this in place of 8, in `L6` cell:

```
IF(AND(OFFSET(L6,-1,-3)=8,OFFSET(L6,1,-3)=8),8,0)
```

You can modify conditions, so they will fit your case in the best way.

This works for Monday-Friday only!